# Matlab complex ones

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices: matrix {a} <252x1> is a subset of matrix {b} <252x4000>. I need to determine the number of days before and after the values of matrix {a} occurred in matrix {b}.

```
Example:

Matrix a  Matrix b
10       12 34 54 10
23       23 98 78 98
43       98 53 43 88
44       98 44 88 78

Output
1  1  1  10
23 1  1  1
1  1  43 1
1  44 1  1

Days
3 0
0 3
2 1
1 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes there is only one match per row:

```
a = [10;23;43;44]
b = [12 34 45 10;23 98 78 98;98 53 43 88; 98 44 88 78]
l = bsxfun(@eq, a, b)
[c r] = find(l')
Days = [c - 1, size(b, 2) - c]
Output = b.*l + ~l
```

If the assumption is bad then I think you'll be better off using loops.

Comment: If the assumption is bad, how would you implement the for loops?

Comment: Start here: l = bsxfun(@eq, a, b) and give it a try. Post your code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is exactly one occurence of `a` in `b` per row:

Use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) to get `result`:

```
result=ones(size(b));
ainb=bsxfun(@eq,a,b);
result(ainb)=b(ainb);
```

Find the column index where `a` is in `b` using [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) with two output arguments, and deduce the number of days from that:

```
[colidx_rev,~] = find(ainb);
colidx(colidx_rev,1) = 1:4;

Days = [colidx-1 size(b,2)-colidx];
```

You'd see that there are multiple matches per row when `any(sum(ainb,2)>1)`. Next thing to do then is selecting one (eg the first match). Do this by finding the column indices in another manner, using a loop or shorter using arrayfun:

```
col_idx = arrayfun(@(rowi) find(ainb(rowi,:),1),1:size(b,1))';
```

the rest is similar.